# In Triage queue, if in my 20th review of the day I click "Looks OK" and it gives me the option to upvote, there are no action buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, triage

It was my last (20th) Triage review of the UTC day.
I clicked "Looks OK".
There were two other users who already okayed the question.
I got to the screen that allows me to upvote the question.
There was no action button to get to the next review.
After upvoting the question, there was still no action button.
Refreshing the page doesn't change anything.
Only going to the stats tab and returning to the review tab shows me the `Thank you for reviewing 20 triage questions...` message.

I would expect that in this case I will have a `Next` button and when clicking it, I'll be shown the `Thank you for reviewing 20 triage questions...` message.

[image]

Comment: Reported already on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280497/missing-next-button-in-the-triage-queue-after-a-successful-looks-ok-review

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't think to look for it there. Isn't MSE the correct place to report such bugs?

Comment: @Eran bugs can be reported on either site. All meta's are monitored for posts with the tag bug so there is no need to post on MSE but it is also not forbidden. The only downside to it might be the cross-site duplicates like you have here. No harm done.

Comment: @bluefeet to this day I'm not sure, are Triage questions on topic here or off topic?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Considering Triage is only on SO, I'd say it would be preferable to ask on MSO but if someone asked here it isn't a big deal, IMO.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks, just saw several such questions being closed recently. Will not vote myself, and refer others to your comment.

Comment: Great, I'll take all the blame @ShadowWizard :P